# How to stream mjpeg using node.js

Tags: node.js, express, jpeg, restify, mjpeg

I need to create a server script by using restify which is streaming mjpeg files over HTTP, the thing is I do not know what steps I should follow for this in the first place, for example I have several pictures, should I combine them as mjpeg file first then send this mjpeg file over HTTP response encoded like multipart/mixed or what? Thanks for the answers. The response should be never ending as I understand it from other .mjpeg servers?

Comment: have you checked FMETP STREAM on asset store? It has node.js Live Streaming demos. 
http://u3d.as/1uHj

Answer (score 1):

I have created this kind of server script but it is not working as I wish, I mean If I refresh the page by clicking F5 on keyboard, the response reloads itself with the next image. Maybe it is caused by restify framework, without restify this runs well.

> ```
> server.get("/app", (req, res, next) => {
>
>     res.writeHead(200, {
>         'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0',
>         Pragma: 'no-cache',
>         Connection: 'close',
>         'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--myboundary'
>     });
>
>     setTimeout(() => {
>
>         if(bufferIndex == bufferArray.length)
>            return bufferIndex = 0
>         res.write(`--myboundary\nContent-Type: image/jpg\nContent-length: ${bufferArray[bufferIndex].length}\n\n`);
>         res.write(bufferArray[bufferIndex]);
>         bufferIndex++
>
>     }, 1000)
>     next()
>
> });
>
>
>
> socketio.on('connection', (socket) => {
>
>     console.log(socket.id)
>
> })
>
>
> server.listen(3000, function () {
>     console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
> });
> ```